# How to make an NTFS Shared Volume Writable

Tags: macos, ntfs

I am on a Macbook Pro with OS X Yosemite. I have another Mac Mini running Windows 8 that I have connected to via a Router.

I am essentially trying to share files from an NTFS volume, but I need to make it writable. I open a Finder window and then do **Go → Connect to Server** and then enter the name of my Mac Mini Shared Folder.

Everything works great, but it's only read only. I've tried editing /etc/fstab using the following [TutsPlus Tutorial](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-write-to-ntfs-drives-in-os-x-mavericks--cms-21434), but that didn't work.

I'm looking into using 'mount_ntfs' on the command line but I just can't get my head around it just yet.

I'd appreciate a little assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NTFS is a **disk file system**. Usually you may access NTFS only by directly attached devices (e.g. PATA, SATA, SCSI etc.)

If you connect to a share over the network you use a **distributed file system** or **network file system**. They do not share block level access to the same storage but use a network protocol (e.g. AFP, SMB, NFS etc.).

Since the NTFS volume is attached to the MacMini, you won't be able to mount it via fstab or mount_ntfs on your MacBook Pro.

Instead check the permissions / ACLs in the file sharing settings in Windows 8.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get it to work, but I really don't know what I did, but I suspect it's when I turned On 'File and Printer Sharing' (across Private, Public and Guest, etc.) under 'Advanced Sharing' in Network Sharing Center in Windows 8.